# set Interval function not working as method

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods, constructor

Can someone tell me why `setInterval` isn't working in this code. I might be missing something and I am not sure what it is. I am trying to run the method `args.counts();`

Error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.cast is not a function at Caste.log
>   (prototype.js:17)

```
    function Caste(){
    this.name = 'James';
    this.surname = 'Penn';
    this.age = 38;

    this.one = document.getElementById('one');
    this.two = document.getElementById('two');

    this.cast = function(){
         return  this.age;
    }
    // ------------------------

    this.log = function(){
        console.log(this.cast());
    }
    // ------------------------
    this.display = function(){
        this.one.innerHTML = this.age;
    }

    this.counts = function(){
     (setInterval(this.log, 2000));
    }
}

// ----------------------

let args = new Caste();
args.counts();
```

Comment: Can you show me the duplicate, Quentin

Comment: Kingsley Ajebon He just did...with the dupe link (which it btw can be closed as even if the questions aren't the same, but the answer solves both)

Comment: ok. Seen. The page didn't load completely before i responded. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` is shorthand for `window.setInterval`, which means that the calling context is `window`, rather than the instantiated object. Either bind the function to the instantiated object:

```
(setInterval(this.log.bind(this), 2000));
```

Or use an arrow function:

```
(setInterval(() => this.log(), 2000));
```

Comment: Excellent. I hope the moderator would leave this thread. From the viewpoint of a newbie, this looks like a different approach to the answer.